# Angular6 - Getting problems & wrong behaviour when trying to implement a nested custom form field inside my form (using Angular Material)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I'm using angular material to create a form where I loop with *ngFor directive to display many inputs of diferent types. What I wanna do is to nest the matInput inside an other component and reuse it inside my form. I think I'm close to making it but I'm stuck for more than 3 days on this console error :

> formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll
>   want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup
>   instance (you can create one in your class).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
> ```

This error makes no sense to me because I already have a [formGroup] directive implemented in my form, as you'll see below. So I wonder how I can resolve this error.

Basically, what I've done so far is follow the guide from material official website : https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#trying-it-out
Here's some code to show you what I've been implementing :

input.component.html

```
<input matInput
  placeholder="placeholder"
  formControlName="formControlName"
/>
```

input.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, HostBinding, Self, Optional, ElementRef, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControlName, ControlValueAccessor, NgControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FocusMonitor } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';


class MyInput {
  constructor(public ftdName: string, public ftdConformite: string, public ftdEmetteur: string,
              public ftdNation: string, public ftdNonConformite: string, public ftdGed: string, 
              public ftdConstatExterne: string) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide : MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: InputComponent
    }]
})

export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<MyInput> {

  static nextId = 0;
  public _placeholder: string;
  public _disabled = false;
  public _required = false;
  public stateChanges = new Subject<void> ();
  public focused = false;
  public errorState = false;
  public listForm: FormGroup;

  onChange: any = () => {}
  onTouch: any = () => {}

  @HostBinding('class.floating')
  get shouldLabelFloat() {
    return this.focused || !this.empty;
  }

  get empty() {
    let n = this.listForm.value;
    return !n.ftdName && !n.ftdConformite && !n.ftdNonConformite && !n.ftdConstatExterne && !n.ftdEmetteur && !n.ftdGed && !n.ftdNation;
  } 

  @HostBinding('attr.aria-describedby') describedBy = '';
  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]) {
    this.describedBy = ids.join(' ');
  }

  @HostBinding() id = `example-myinput-${InputComponent.nextId++}`

  @Input() 
  formControlName: FormControlName;

  @Input() 
  get placeholder() {
    return this._placeholder
  }
  set placeholder(plh) {
    this._placeholder = plh;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get required() {
    return this._required;
  }
  set required(req) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(req);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get disabled(): boolean {
     return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(value: boolean) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this._disabled ? this.listForm.disable() : this.listForm.enable();
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl : NgControl,
  fb: FormBuilder, private fm: FocusMonitor, private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { 

    this.listForm = fb.group({
      'ftdName' : '',
      'ftdConformite' : '',
      'ftdEmetteur' : '',
      'ftdNation' : '',
      'ftdNonConformite' : '',
      'ftdGed' : '', 
      'ftdConstatExterne' : ''
    })

    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true)
    .subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });

    if(this.ngControl != null) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this
    }
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if ((event.target as Element).tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
  }

  set value(input : MyInput | null) {
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  // this method sets the value programmatically
  writeValue(value:any) {
    this.value = value
  }
  // upon UI element value changes, this method gets triggered
  registerOnChange(fn: any){
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  // upon touching the element, this method gets triggered
  registerOnTouched(fn: any){
    this.onTouch = fn
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

form.component.html (where I call my app-input, I simplify the code to show only the part that concerns my problem.)

```
<div class="matContainer">
  <form class="EventForm" [formGroup]="listForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitList()">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of jsonArrays.groups; let last = last">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let input of group.inputs">

        <mat-form-field *ngIf="input.type === 'matInput'" class="colonne{{ 
         input.colonne }}">
          <app-input 
            placeholder="{{ input.placeholder }}"
            formControlName="{{ input.formControlName }}"
          ></app-input>
        </mat-form-field>

      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </form>
</div>
```

As a result, I am able to see my inputs that are normally being displayed only if I click on the first input (that is always displayed), or if I resize my page, I have no clue of that behaviour. 
 But still, the error message in console is still display no matter what.
 If you have any questions, or things I can clarify don't hesitate, I'll be glad to.

Comment: can you share a minimal stackblitz of your code... it'll be easier to help

Comment: Heya, I'll try to make a stackblitz but many dependencies seems not available on Stackblitz, like the import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';

Comment: do these dependencies cause (or are part of) the issue in your question?

Comment: No, all dependencies are fine on my project, I can run my app without problems ^.^

Comment: Here is the stackblitz but with dependencies errors, at least you can see better the structure of the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wan84s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshare-data.service.ts

Comment: Even with your dependencies fixed (path errors - don't import from 'src'), there are many problems with your code and it doesn't look complete. Please fix.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upela1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts Here is a new stackblitz, with many of the features of my project, but still "Cant find package : src". Src dependencie (1.1.2) is installed in stackblitz as you can see in dependencies. I've checked many times and everything is exactly as my original code so it's supposed to work as its working for me ^.^

Comment: @Hotsockets src is not a dependency that you need to install. You need to fix your imports and make them relative, e.g. in share-data.service.ts change the EventModel import to `import { EventModel } from '../models/event.model';` Do that for all imports your custom imports which aren't relative (see [module-resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)). There is also a folder called 'dialogs' missing.

Comment: @coreuter thx for your help, I managed to fix many many errors that stackblitz had because of relatives path mainly. This stackblitz really starting to give me headaches because, despite the fact it doesnt reproduce my header and my left sidebar (wich u dont really need for the problem), I have an other error that I already fixed on my local machine. Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upela1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbody%2Fevent-process-and-display%2Fevent-edit-process%2FmatInput-components%2Finput%2Finput.component.ts , I'm trully sorry that i'm not able to help you guys more

Comment: Oh and I fixed my initial problem on my local machine, but I'm afraid that it's a bit rough as a solution, I basically added a div with formGroup like this `<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input matInput
  placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
  formControlName="{{formControlName}}"
  />
 </div>` and no errors, everything works fine (less the floating behaviour but Im working on this), I can recieve datas I type in my inputs... I just though it's strange to get a formGroup for every input I generate